# Jenkins pipeline for react could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH

Tags: java, reactjs, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm running a jenkins pipeline. At the last step my sonar analysis raises an error :

```
var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner/bin/sonar-scanner
Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
```

I set my JAVA_HOME in my centos 7, and when I run echo $JAVA_HOME I got :

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64
```

The error is raises in the file sonar-scanner :

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]
then
  java_cmd="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
else
  java_cmd="$(which java)"
fi

java_cmd="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java"
echo $java_cmd
#export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64
if [ -z "$java_cmd" -o ! -x "$java_cmd" ] ; then
  echo "Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH."
  exit 1
fi
```

I tried many solutions but still got the same error, please, I could I correct it ?

My jenkins pipeline script :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine'
            args '-v /home/nginx/console:/home -p 3000:3000'

        }
    }
        environment {
        CI = 'true' 
    }

    stages {
        stage('Install') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm test' 
            }
        }

        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm run build' 
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') { 
            steps {
                sh 'cp -R dist/* /home' 
            }
        }

        stage('Sonarqube analysis') {

            steps {


                script {
                    scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner';

                }
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
                        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner" 
                }

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the path is correctly set. That's why when I run echo $JAVA_HOME, I got the correct path. But why sonar can't find this path ?

Comment: But is it *exported?* The fact is that your computer doesn't agree with you.

Comment: You specify the global agent to docker image `'node:6-alpine'`, all stages will be executed in the container launched from this image, unless you specify agent at stage level to overwrite the global agent.  If the docker image not setup JAVA, the error is expected.

Comment: @yong thanks for your answer. You said " all stages will be executed in the container launched from this image", but this container is mounted to use variables declared in Jenkins...So you think that the solution is to create a pipeline based on java to run this specific step ?

Comment: you can specify a java docker image as `agent`  for `stage('Sonarqube analysis')`, jenkins will mount job workspace to container, therefor your source code in job workspace can be accessed in container when sonar scan. No need to separate sonar scan into another pipeline job. Or you can use `tool <jdk installation>` to supply `java`  if you had configured it in Jenkins Admin,without using java docker image.

Comment: Ok, i will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommandation of yong, I created this jenkinsfile and succeeded to push on sonar :

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment {
        CI = 'true' 
    }

    stages {
        stage('Install') { 

            agent { docker 'node:6-alpine'     }
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }
        stage('Test') { 
            agent { docker 'node:6-alpine'      }
            steps {

                sh 'npm test' 
            }
        }

        stage('Build') { 
            agent { docker 'node:6-alpine'      }
            steps {

                sh 'npm run build' 
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') { 
            agent { docker 'node:6-alpine'     }
            steps {

                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'vm-int', transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', execCommand: 'sudo cp -R /var/jenkins_home/workspace/myapp/dist/* /home/nginx/console/', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '/home/nginx/console/', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myapp/dist/*')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
            }
        }

        stage('Sonarqube analysis') {
           agent {     docker   'maven:3-alpine'   }

            steps {

                script {
                    scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner';

                }
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
                        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner" 
                }

            }
        }


    }
}
```